# MapInfo 'Info' tool - querying by polygon rather than at a point

Tags: mapinfo, query, tools, extensions, add-ons

MapInfo Professional (12.5) has a tool called 'Info' which interrogates the data for all visible and selectable tables when the user clicks at a specific point. It lists all objects from all tables, and then allows the user to click on each one to view the attributes and values of that object.

Are any MapInfo Pro users aware of a tool which can do this over an area?

For example, showing all objects from all visible tables over a user-defined polygon, or within a user-specified radius from a point?

Answer (score 2):

That's a great idea for a inspection tool. Unfortunately, MapInfo Pro doesn't have such a tool right now.

It could quite easily be created with MapBasic if you have any knowledge in that area.

1. Let the user draw a polygon
2. Loop thru all the layers and find the objects intersecting the drawn polygon
3. In a dialog show the layers that did intersect, and the when the user clicks on a layer show the records that intersect.